# How to reset Ubuntu's Keyboard Media Short Cut back to Default

Tags: shortcut-keys, media-buttons

While testing the media keyboard shortcuts for various players, I change the hotkeys to keystrokes.  Now I'm trying to get them back to the defaults.

The prompt shows options for either setting a new key by hitting the keystroke, or to clear the setting by hitting the backspace.  I don't see an option to change it to the default.

The defaults have words, for instance the **Play (or play/pause)** has the words, **Audio play** and the **Pause playback** has the words **Audio pause**.

I'm trying to get the default settings back where it has the words.  Some of the media apps don't work well with the keystrokes I have assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortcut setting are stored/saved on `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys`

1. Install [*Dconf editor*](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-editor/) [image: Install banshee]
2. Launch *dconf Editor*
3. Navigate to **org** > **gnome** > **settings-daemon** > **plugins** > **media-keys**

The entry that involving media shortcut is:

```
XF86Audiomedia
XF86Audionext
XF86AudioPlay
XF86AudioPause
XF86AudioPrev
XF86AudioLowerVolume
XF86AudioMute
XF86AudioRaiseVolume
```

Select desired entry, then press "Set to Default" button to reset each entry.

[image]